# How to change part of a webpage crawled by Scrapy before saving on disk?

Tags: python, scrapy

In the `parse()` method of a Scrapy spider, we can use the `css()` method on `response` to grab the needed information. For example, we can use `response.css("#container")` to get the following HTML snippet.

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="sep">test</div>
    ...
</div>
```

How can we change part of the HTML snippet before saving on disk? For example, I want to change the text content of `<div class="sep">` to `1234` so that the final needed HTML snippet looks like

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="sep">1234</div>
    ...
</div>
```

I know I can save the raw HTML snippet on disk and later use an HTML parser to change it. However, that will essentially parse it again, as it has already been parsed in the `response` parameter of the `parse()` method in the Scrapy spider. I check the Scrapy document and I can only find ways to get information from a page. How can I do *set* operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy is specifically targeted at extracting information; as such, it doesn't provide any functionality for modifying HTML.

However, nothing is stopping you from importing your favorite parser and using it.
Alternatively, the `root` attribute of a selector will give you access to the underlying lxml element. I'm fairly certain that you would have to dump the root element using lxml though.

Scrapy only parses the source once you access `response.selector` (either directly or through one of extraction methods).
If you want to avoid parsing twice, simply don't use those.